# NetInfo returns true when connected to wifi but no internet

Tags: react-native

NetInfo returns true when connected to wifi but there is no internet. So apart from NetInfo what are the other best options to check internet connectivity in react native?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately there is no alternative to pinging some kind of host and wait for the response.

You could do something like this:

```
poll() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    poll();

    return fetch('http://www.google.com')
      .then((response) => {
        // this is the success callback
        // you could check if the app was previously offline
        // and set it back to online to get rid of the offline hint
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // error callback
        // use this to handle some sort of notification for the user
        // you could update a state within your root container
        // or redux to update the app with some visual hints
      });
  }, 5000);
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! can you elaborate how I can use the offline status. I'm unable to do this    .catch(('offline') => {
    alert(offline)
    })

Comment: Oh, sorry, that was meant as `in here is pseudocode`, I'll update the example

Comment: thanks for the edit but how can you tell that fetch request entered in catch block just because of no internet it could be some other issue as well like web api server is inaccessible or something similar.

Comment: true, it could be, if the google server is down - as server uptime goes, this is your best bet.

I mean if you want to have it 'bulletproof', you could check several hosts and use the aggregated result plus the netinfo stuff and have a high chance of knowing if you have a connection to the internet.

As server uptime goes though, I think one can be pretty sure, that google doesn't go down..

Comment: @devedv feel free to mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: setTimeout is really a very bad practice

Comment: also you need to add headers to avoid Cache and using "head" instead of "get" for faster response.

Comment: hey @FareedAlnamrouti, 
what happened to your answer? 

Why did you delete it?

Comment: I found that the react native standard solution works perfect on the real device and the issues only on the simulator

Answer (score 4):

You have to ping and see if connection actually has internet connection.
First use netInfo. Using it's **icConnected** method find out if the device is connected to a network. If so use your HTTP client to add an interceptor and try to ping and check internet connectivity before sending the actual request.

Also if you need more advanced stuff try out this library to work with offline data. It'll solve your problem.
https://github.com/rauliyohmc/react-native-offline

Comment: Updated the answer.