# How to determine that the Internet is not stable in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am working on a react native app that is online first application and it requires a stable internet connection to work properly, that's why i need to find a solution to check if the internet is stable and not laggy.
I’ve already used [RN community netinfo lib](https://github.com/react-native-netinfo/react-native-netinfo) to check if the internet is connected or not.

However, if the device is connected to WIFI and if there is no access to the internet, the isConnected value returned from the package is `true`.

**My main purpose for this question is to check the quality of the internet, if it is not stable and poor I will display a hint or warning to make the user aware of his connectivity**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NetInfo returns true when connected to wifi but no internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49353963/netinfo-returns-true-when-connected-to-wifi-but-no-internet)

Comment: @user18309290 this question answered a part of my question, but I need to know when the internet is not stable (slow) as well.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to download some package and calculate the speed by checking how much time it took to download that.
You can also use some some plugin like https://github.com/TSjianjiao/react-native-network-speed